# How to use OnDraw in MFC-Dialog

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc

I'm in the MFC Using OpenGL, But my projects Is a dialog,I can't find OnDraw,so I using OnPaint,
When I want to compute the FPS,Using OnPaint is wrong,OnPaint only in change Window work,so What should I do? likeness RenderLoop .

this is my projects!
https://github.com/Puuupa/MFC_OpenGL.git

Comment: Must CView?   can't be used Dialog using OpenGL ?

Comment: Isn't there a full blown OpenGL in MFC dialogs example coming with Visual C++? It's been 20 years, but I dimly recall that being part of the installation.

Answer (score 2):

Create a dedicated "control" window for the OpenGL rendering. Register this as custom control and put that into the dialog.

At least, that's how I remember, how it's done. It's been 20 years since I've used OpenGL together with the MFC.

Why are you using the MFC at all anyway, they've been deprecated for ages.